# VS Code report @support in scss mode that } expected

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code, scss-lint

How can I somehow add @support into a known syntax for scss linter in VS Code?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug as of VS Code 1.15. We are tracking the issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28553)